# Postgre AsBinary within Oracle

Tags: oracle, postgis, oracle-spatial

i have to migrate some postgis stuff to oracle database 11.2.

can you tell me the best oracle pendant for postgis AsBinary(Geometry)?

edit:
my try.

SDO_UTIL.TO_WKBGEOMETRY(

```
 geometry IN SDO_GEOMETRY

 ) RETURN BLOB;
```

DONE

Answer (score 0):

Use `ogr2ogr` with the [Oracle Spatial](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_oci.html) driver. E.g.:

```
ogr2ogr -f OCI OCI:username/password PG:dbname=databasename
```